# MINUS clause in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

My question is or seems to be easy.
I would like to subtract 2 queries in Access 2007.
The problem is that in query1 some records are identical (yes - I need them).
Query2 records are distinct.

Query1:

```
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
5  6  7  8
```

Query2:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

Query1 - Query2
Expected result:

```
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Marian

Comment: Might `Query1` include any rows which are unmatched by `Query2`?  If yes, what should happen with those?  Should they be included in the expected result set?

Comment: All query2 rows are included in query1.

Answer (score 0):

You should revise those queries to bring forward:

- a *unique key* from its table(s) for Query1
- the *max of the unique key* for Query2

The you can write a query that retrieves those records in Query1 *NOT IN* Query2.

Comment: Thank you Gustav.

Comment: Gustav - sorry but your solution is not very clear to me, can you please come with a small sql script solution for the exact above expected result.

Comment: That will be difficult, as I don't have your queries.

Comment: Query1, Query2, Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4. The names of the fields are the same in both queries. The data and expected result is in my question. Thank you,

Comment: OK, but it is _Query1_ and _Query2_ that have to be modified.

Comment: Can anyone else help with my question ?

Comment: If you keep your queries secret, it will be difficult.